# Fill gaps in a time-series off by an hour due to timezone/DST change

Tags: r, time-series, dst, zoo

I have a time-series with aggregated data (different intervals, e.g. 1 day, 12 hours and 30 min). The data looks as follows:

```
           open    close     high      low
2013-01-21 16.62600 17.13600 17.13600 16.62600
2013-01-22 17.21240 17.74800 17.85000 17.18699
2013-01-23 17.40467 17.93721 17.93721 17.21760
2013-01-24 18.00399 17.23800 19.53516 16.52400
2013-01-25 16.99912 17.74800 18.14193 15.88218
```

For some intervals the data is missing and I would like to fill these gaps. In order to do that I merge the data with a zoo object based on the sequence from start to end.

```
data.full = merge(data,zoo(,seq(start(data),end(data),by=interval)), all=TRUE)
```

Unfortunately the sequence seems to be based on 24 hours and not on days. So once summer time starts the created sequence is off by one hour and the merge does not work anymore (and the time zone obviously changes from CET to CEST).

The zoo sequence looks as follows:

```
2013-03-28 00:00:00 CET
2013-03-29 00:00:00 CET
2013-03-30 00:00:00 CET
2013-03-31 00:00:00 CET
2013-04-01 01:00:00 CEST
2013-04-02 01:00:00 CEST
2013-04-03 01:00:00 CEST
2013-04-04 01:00:00 CEST
2013-04-05 01:00:00 CEST
```

What is the easiest (and most flexible way) to get rid of that problem? I could change the format in the zoo object manually, but I would like to use the code for different intervals.

Comment: You could switch your session to UTC, `Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')` as that does not use DST or use chron date/times which don't use timezones.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Maybe you have already set the time zones on your data before you set it globally or maybe you have made some other error but using UTC does not use DST and chron does not use time zones at all so either of these if done correctly would nsolve it.

Comment: Found the mistake. When converting the timestamp into a POSIXct object I didn't specify a timestamp. Added 'tz = "UTC"' there and now it works just fine. Thanks!